# Importing a shared object in python using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to call my `.so` file from a python script. I've used `pybind11` a to build the `.so` with a "hello" function that I want to call from my Python code. Apparently for it to be imported it needs to have a certain name like this: "libtest.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so". With this I can import it as "libtest" and then call my hello function (which is inside the shared object). But there are two problems:

1. My IDE (`CLion`) does not seem to understand what is being imported at all and highlights the `import libtest` as an error, even though I can execute it normally. (This is probably not a question for SO, but if someone knows please let me know as well)
2. I can only import the `libtest` module if the .so is in the same folder as my python script. Is there a way to import it independently of the path, for example, can I import it from `/usr/bin`? I have tried adding it to $PATH but this didn't seem to do anything. So how is it possible to "bundle" the `.so` and script so they can easily be downloaded?

Comment: One question per post please. For the second one, it's likely too broad to be answered. You'll want to read how to write a setup file for pybind11 and install your package that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you need to create a [stub file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html) named `libtest.pyi` in the same folder as your `.so` to have your IDE know that the functionality exists.
2. python uses `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to find modules, the path to the `.so` needs to be on it, not `PATH`.